# Should I volunteer to make additional hands-on assignment to prove my skills?

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process, applications

A couple months ago I applied for a Software Developer position and went through quite lengthy, multiple-stages interview process. It was focused on my Python experience, although I also had an opportunity to briefly mention I worked with JS and React. After last round I was informed my performance was good enough, but unfortunately company had to cut headcount and close the position they wanted to recruit me for.

Now I'm being approached by the recruiter from that company, and informed that although they still don't recruit full-time, they would like to consider me for a short-term contractor role (in the same team, and for similar project). The recruiter told me they're also considering two other people, and they will have to make decision if they want to hire someone with Python knowledge (me), or someone with JavaScript skills (other people). I responded that I have both set-skills, but I haven't got any acknowledge it makes any difference.

Does it makes sense for me to do hands-on coding assignment in JavaScript and send it to the recruiter as a showcase of my frontend skills? I had to code a simple game in Python during the previous process, so I could make the same game in JavaScript.

On the one hand it would prove I actually can code in JavaScript, on the other they weren't really interested in my frontend skills when I interviewed with them last time, so maybe it's not that important for them and there are other consideration in place that they didn't want to share? Also isn't it too zealous to spend time on the assignment nobody is expecting me to provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voluntarily doing extra work during a hiring process isn't typically done, so it's hard for us to predict how the hiring manager will react. They may be impressed by your skills and your initiative, or they may ignore it. Or, worse, they may see a mistake in it and decide to rule you out as a candidate. Unfortunately, none of us know what will happen.

It sounds like you've already informed them that you have Javascript skills, and they haven't followed up on that comment. Depending on your relationship with this recruiter, and exactly how that communication was worded, it might make sense to follow up (ideally via phone call) and say something like,

> I know I mentioned that I have JavaScript skills - if you think those skills may be important for your position, I'd be happy to reproduce the simple game I coded in Python during the last interview, but in JavaScript. Let me know if you'd be interested in seeing that.

This way, you can *offer* to do it, and see how they react, without spending any actual time or effort on something that may not care about.

Comment: That's the answer that I cam here to write :-)